# regular expression conditional validation

Tags: regex

sample input text:

a) `owner.table_name`
b) `table_name`

1. can somebody suggest regular expression so that I get out put in such a way that i get text upto "." (if "." exists) and if "." doesnt exist then return empty

   output:

   a) `owner`

   b) empty
2. regular expression so that I get out put in such a way that I get text from "." up to end (if "." exists) and if "." doesn't exist then return entire string

   output:

   a) `table_name`

   b) `table_name`

Comment: Are you looking for `owner(\.table_name)?`?

Comment: Why not use one regular expression (with matching groups) for both tasks?

Comment: [Have you tried anything?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com) It usually helps to know what you've already attempted so that we don't reiterate things that haven't worked for you.

Comment: Cyborg37 names it, we need some code. It would be useful to know your programming language, to give you some boilerplate code too (e.g. accessing capture groups of your regex)

Comment: I am using oracle posix. for 1) i tried '[^.]*' and for 2)  tried '\.(\w+)' but both does not solve the case where there is no "."

Answer (score 2):

The following regex should work:

```
(?:(\w+)\.)?(\w+)
```

It creates two capture groups (see [this debuggex example](http://www.debuggex.com/?re=%28?%3a%28%5Cw%2b%29%5C.%29?%28%5Cw%2b%29&flags=&str=owner.table_name) to play around with it)
The first group will be empty, with the input `table_name`. For `owner.table_name` both groups have the appropriate values.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a regex that would match both in one:

```
((?<owner>\w+)\.)?(?<table>\w+)
```

If the tool you are using allows named groups, the first group will be called "owner" and will be any word before a period. The second group will be called "table" and will be any word after a possible "owner".